# Hibernate with Spring : How to decrypt the database password put in properties file for hibernate configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate

Below is my bean in hibernate-config.xml file

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${indy.web.database.host}:${indy.web.database.port}/${indy.web.database.name}" />
        <property name="user" value="${indy.web.database.login}" />
        <property name="password" value="${indy.web.database.password}" />
    </bean>
```

All the values inside ${} are coming through properties file and get set automatically.
But my password in properties file is in encrypted format so I want to set it after decrypting it.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve this is to use jasypt provided property placeholder configurer instead of the build property palceholder configurer.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
  class="org.jasypt.spring3.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
 <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
 <property name="locations">
  <list>
    <value>/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

Full configuration details available on this page-
http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html

Comment: I have my own encryption and decryption algorithm and I have to use that as it is used in my other non-spring services

Comment: You can either configure the encryption alogrithm using the jasypt or implement your own PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer (that extends the springs PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer)  similar to the EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Answer (score 0):

Define a Spring FactoryBean, which will decode the 'password' value & return it. Factory Beans can be used to answer/ calculate values, as well as creating objects.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html

Referencing the bean in your Spring configuration, will then give you the *answered value*.

If you need the value in Properties object & can't otherwise get it in there, you could create a Properties factory which would incorporate a decoded value with configured properties.

Answer (score 0):

Sublass MysqlDataSource with your class

Something like this:

```
public class DatasourceWithEncPass extends MysqlDataSource{
   public void setPassword(String passowrd){
     //decrypt the password here before setting it
   }
 ..
}
```

Use this class in context:

```
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.yourpackage.DatasourceWithEncPass">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${indy.web.database.host}:${indy.web.database.port}/${indy.web.database.name}" />
        <property name="user" value="${indy.web.database.login}" />
        <property name="password" value="${indy.web.database.password}" />
    </bean>
```